What's the workaround for Django/PostgreSQL GeneratedField error
When defining a GeneratedField with PostgreSQL, it is not uncommon to encounter the following error: django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: generation expression is not immutable.
This error is mentioned in the docs about PostgreSQL-specific restriction:

...PostgreSQL requires functions and operators referenced in a generated column to be marked as IMMUTABLE.

This error occurs with almost all Func() expressions (with a specified database function). For example:
age_func = Func("date_of_birth", function="age")
age_years = Func(Value("year"), age_func, function="date_part", output_field=...)

This will throw the above error if age_years is used in GeneratedField expression.
Another reproducible example is with Concat() function. If used as is, Concat will also raise the same error, but there is a workaround for it (this custom implementation may not be necessary in Django 5.1).
If I was defining these functions in sql, I suppose it wouldn't be a problem marking them as IMMUTABLE. My question is, working with only Django, how do we implement IMMUTABLE functions/expressions?
I assume there is a way of passing extra arguments/options that will be used to specify whether the database function will be IMMUTABLE, STABLE, VOLATILE, etc., but I have no clue how to specify this. Perhaps we could subclass Func and override some sql-generating method, but again, I don't know which one is responsible.

The result from function age() changes every microsecond. There is also the question why you would even store the age since you can calculate this very efficient when needed.

I don't really see why you would need a calculated field here? You can easily use .annotate(..) when needed, and filtering will be (almost) as efficient by just using the __gt and __lt on the date_of_birth.

I am annotating the age field (through a custom manager) when reading the database. The problem is when I need to access this table from a related table, e.g., following a reverse lookup. But most importantly, this is only an example. I just need to know what's the workaround.

You can not use a generated column if the expression is time sensitive. Indeed, if it depends for example on NOW(), or RANDOM() or anything that is not determinsitic, it does not work, or at least not for now. But it is probably non-sensical anyway: a generated column is a column that is calculated and stored in the table. If your age depends on the current time, it means that every day, records should be updated, defeating the entire purpose of a generated column.
But it is here probably also not useful anyway: you can use .annotate(…) [Django-doc] to determine the age when necessary. If you want to filter, you can use:
from datetime import date

Person.objects.filter(date_of_birth__range=(date(1994, 7, 16), date(1995, 7, 16)))
for people that are, at the moment, 29 years old.

This makes sense.
To have a setup that makes sense, one option (that I'm already using), is to simply annotate the age column. However, it becomes a problem when I need to access the annotated column from a related table. For example, I can't do: Customer.objects.filter(person__age__range=(...)), the table will not have the field age even if overriding the default model manager. This makes sense. This limitation doesn't apply to GeneratedFields, that's why I'm desperate to make it work.

You can annotate it with Customer.objects.annotate(age=Age('person__date_of_birth')).filter(age=25)

Then I will be repeating the same logic across multiple tables. Suppose I have four/five tables related to Person, and in all those I need the age column. It's tedious.

You can also use managers to automatically plug in the age.

That's what I'm currently doing. I'm overriding the initial queryset and override the default model manager. But after doing it with two models, I realised it's not DRY if I have to do it to more models. I wanted to avoid that

@McPherson: you can work with a mixin in the managers to avoid duplication. I don't really see how generated columns would make it more dry, since it is essentially the same "technique".
